# Callable Firebase Function Nothing Happens On Button Click

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am new to firebase functions and just trying to do a simple test - click on a button to invoke a callable firebase function.

The firebase function is just a simple console.log message.  For this project I am using Angular.

I have provided my front-end and back-end code snippets below.

When I click on the button, for some reason nothing happens.  I expected for the firebase function to be invoked and receive 'hello world' message in my console.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```js
Index.js

exports.test = functions.https.onCall(() => {
    console.log('hello world');
});
```

```js
test() {
    firebase.functions().httpsCallable('test');
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.2/firebase-functions.js"></script>

<script>
    var config = {
        apiKey: 'xxx',
        authDomain: 'xxx',
        databaseURL: 'xxx',
        storageBucket: 'xxx'
    };

    // Initialize Cloud Functions through Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    var functions = firebase.functions();
</script>

<button (click)="test()">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't actually invoking the function.  When you call [httpsCallable()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.functions.Functions#httpscallable), you will need to capture its return value, which is an [HttpsCallable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.functions.HttpsCallable) object you use to actually invoke the function.

```
test() {
    const test = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('test');
    test.call();
}
```

Note that test() returns a promise that give you the return value from the function.

I suggest reviewing the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.functions.HttpsCallable) for more information.